# How do I pass a PHP variable from one file to another multiple times?

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I have a highstock graph in a file called charts.php that reloads the graph data from a secondary file called data.php. Seeing as I have 5 series in my highstock graph I have to call the data.php file 5 times, each time using a different variable, but when I set the variable in my charts.php file it only uses the last set value of this variable. Is is possible to solve this, or is this just the way PHP works? Do I have to create 5 separate data.php files in order for this to work?

Here's basically what my code looks like (showing 2 series to keep it short):

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart'
    },

    title : { text : 'MyChart' },

    series : [
        {
            name : 'Unit 0',
            data : [],
            tooltip: { valueDecimals: 1, valueSuffix: ' kW' },
        },
        {
            name : 'Unit 1',
            data : [],
            tooltip: { valueDecimals: 1, valueSuffix: ' kW' },
        }
    ]
});

<?php $_SESSION["unit"] = 0; ?>

$.getJSON( "data.php", function (data) {
    chart.series[0].setData( data );
});

<?php $_SESSION["unit"] = 1; ?>

$.getJSON( "data.php", function (data) {
    chart.series[1].setData( data );
});
```

So the problem is that both series[0] and series[1] use the last value of my variable, which in this case is $_SESSION["unit"] = 1. Is the a way to make this work? Any better alternatives?

Maybe if I could create data for all of the series in one file and somehow split that data and pass it to series[0] and series[1] separately, but I have no idea how to do that..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you use a for loop maybe ? Not sure what the session variable is doing here since there does not seem to be some code there that makes use of the value in that session variable.

Comment: You're definitely doing it wrong. Instead of using AJAX to load the contents of data.php use PHP to load the contents of data.php. If you need to pass different data to it, use a function and pass the data to the function instead. How you are doing it is very inefficient.

Comment: using sesssion variable doesn't make much sense at all, why aren't you just using data in request itself? Also if it was me would pass array for all data in one request and initialize chart in callback of that request

Comment: I have some PHP code in data.php that uses this variable in order to create the data (which is different depending on this variable). If i had different files then I could use a for loop I guess.

Comment: @dansan every time you do `$.getJSON` the browser needs to make a separate request to the server and this is very bad. It creates a higher load on the server and makes things significantly slower on the client-side completely unnecessarily. Wrap whatever you have in `data.php` up in a function that returns the JSON and takes whatever you need to pass to it as a parameter and just echo it to the browser.

Comment: Another major problem with the logic of your code is that you are getting client-side and server-side code mixed up. JavaScript is run by the client and PHP is run on the server. So doing `$_SESSION["unit"] = 0` and then `$_SESSION["unit"] = 1` is exactly the same as just doing `$_SESSION["unit"] = 1`. You can't just put PHP variables before your javascript and expect that PHP will use them server-side when you do your AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could modify your data.php file, so instead of using `$_SESSION["unit"]` to determine which var to use, use `$_GET["unit"]` instead. Then, in your code above, it would be:

```
$.getJSON( "data.php?unit=0", function (data) {
    chart.series[0].setData( data );
});

$.getJSON( "data.php?unit=1", function (data) {
    chart.series[1].setData( data );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked prefectly! Now I guess there's still better ways to do this, but at least I don't have to create separate files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, if the $unit values are always the same I would just call data.php once and update all the graphs at once using the JS response.

If $unit has a dynamic variable I would send it along with the $.getJSON function.

```
var data = {
  unit: $_GET['unit']
};

$.getJSON( "data.php", data, function (response) {
  updateGraph(graph, response);
});
```

For more on getJSON on the structure of the function, visit http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/